# Flying Saucer in Landscape mode

Tags: itext, flying-saucer

We would like to be able to render arbitrary HTML pages in PDF format, **landscape mode**, using Flying Saucer.  All suggestions that we have come across so far require tinkering with CSS and/or HTML.  Is there no other way to do it (e.g. by setting some API parameter)?

Comment: Flying Saucer is not an iText product. If you want to convert HTML to PDF with iText, then you need to use [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfhtml), that allows you to define the PDF document output (size/orientation) using the `PdfDocument` object.

Comment: @André Lemos Your statement seems to contradict what Bruno Lowagie, the original developer of iText, says in his book **"iText in Action"**.  Bruno mentions that " … xhtmlrenderer, aka **Flying Saucer ---a project that is built on top of iText**".

Comment: indeed, it was built on top of iText, by someone else. Check out what the man answered in a [similar question yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698455/want-to-generate-landscape-pdf-using-flying-saucer#comment76401397_44698455)